# Real Analysis Archimedian Property

Tags: real-analysis

If $x, y$ are real numbers, with $x < y$, show that $$x < ty + (1-t)x < y$$ for all $t$ such that $ 0 < t < 1$.

I know we need to use Archimedian principle, and I think it may be used twice, but I'm stuck on how to get the extra $x$ in there from $t(y-x) > 1$.

Any help would be great!

Comment: Archimedian isn't necessary.

Answer (score -1):

Since $x<y$ and $0<t<1$ so
$$x=tx+(1-t)x<ty+(1-t)x<ty+(1-t)y=y$$
Now let $x<z<y$, define the function $f:[0,1]\rightarrow [x,y]$ with 
$$f(t)=ty+(1-t)x=t(x-y)+x$$
then $f(0)=x$ and $f(1)=y$ and also continuous injective, now mean value theorem implies that there is $t_0$ such that $f(t_0)=z$.

Comment: we cannot assume 0 < t < 1 because we have to show that, right?

Comment: @Savannah: Not at all. We have to **assume** that $0<t<1,$ and *show* that if $x,y\in\Bbb R$ with $x<y,$ then $x<ty+(1-t)x<y.$

Comment: @Savannah answer is ok now for you?

Comment: Yes, thank you!